# Open SDK Can't open Excel file when running on web server but is working in localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I've a C# Web forms application and I want to export contents of a gridview to excel using Open XML SDK 2.5.  This working perfectly when I run in localhost but its not working when I move my app to the UAT webserver and I'm getting no error.  I figure this is a premissions error but not sure. Thanks,

```
 DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet;
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet worksheet;
        System.IO.StreamReader styleXmlReader;
        string styleXml;

        spreadsheet = Excel.CreateWorkbook(workbookName);
        if (spreadsheet == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (createStylesInCode)
        {
            Excel.AddBasicStyles(spreadsheet);
        }
        else
        {
            using (styleXmlReader = new     
  System.IO.StreamReader("PredefinedStyles.xml"))
            {
                styleXml = styleXmlReader.ReadToEnd();
                Excel.AddPredefinedStyles(spreadsheet, styleXml);
            }
        }

        Excel.AddSharedString(spreadsheet, "Shared string");
        Excel.AddWorksheet(spreadsheet, "Test 1");
        Excel.AddWorksheet(spreadsheet, "Test 2");
        worksheet = 
spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet;

        // Headings
        Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, 1, 1, "QMS Area", 
true);
        Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, 2, 1, "Division 
Owner", true);
        Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, 3, 1, "Relevant 
Divisions", true);
        Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, 4, 1, "Audit Team", 
true);
        Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, 5, 1, "Audit Date", 
true);


        int _rowCount = 2;
        foreach (var audit in _auditDetails)
        {
            // Set Values
            Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, 1, 
(uint)_rowCount, audit.QmsArea, true);
            Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, 2, 
(uint)_rowCount, audit.DivisionOwner ?? "", true);
            Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, 3, 
(uint)_rowCount, audit.RelevantDivision ?? "", true);
            Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, 4, 
(uint)_rowCount, audit.AuditTeam ?? "", true);
            Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, 5, 
(uint)_rowCount, audit.AuditDate.ToString() ?? "", true);             
            _rowCount++;
        }



        // Set column widths
        Excel.SetColumnWidth(worksheet, 1, 15);
        Excel.SetColumnWidth(worksheet, 2, 20);

        worksheet.Save();
        spreadsheet.Close();


        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(workbookName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the folder permissions on the server where the excel files are being saved. You need to make sure that your web app has read/write permissions for that folder.

The fact that it is working on your local machine, but not on the hosted environment, makes me think the folder permissions may be the issue.

Comment: yes I noticed that the file is being saved into  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv but I've given full permissions to the excel file in this folder and its still not working.

Comment: Did you give full permissions to the folder that the file is contained in as well?